# Python Paramiko SSH server fails on PTY allocation

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pty

I have to debug a software that communicates via SSH. Since I need to know exactly what the software is sending in the communication and decrypting the SSH communication is not easy, I want to make a Python SSH server-client that accepts the communication from the software, transports all its messages to the actual server and prints them in my terminal.

I got code from [Creating Python SSHServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368098/creating-python-sshserver), which I managed to execute getting the RSA key from Paramiko GitHub page:

```
import os
import paramiko
import socket
import sys
import threading

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
HOSTKEY = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=os.path.join(CWD, '.test_rsa.key'))

class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        
    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED
        
    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if (username == 'tim') and (password == 'sekret'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = '127.0.0.1'
    ssh_port = 22
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((server, ssh_port))
        sock.listen(100)
        print('[+] Listening for connection ...')
        client, addr = sock.accept()
    except Exception as e:
        print('[-] Listen failed: ' + str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print(f'[+] Got a connection! from {addr}')
        
    bhSession = paramiko.Transport(client)
    bhSession.add_server_key(HOSTKEY)
    server = Server()
    bhSession.start_server(server=server)
    
    chan = bhSession.accept(20)
    if chan is None:
        print('*** No channel.')
        sys.exit(1)
        
    print('[+] Authenticated!')
    print(chan.recv(1024).decode())
    chan.send('Welcome to bh_ssh')
    try:
        while True:
            command = input("Enter command: ")
            if command != 'exit':
                chan.send(command)
                r = chan.recv(8192)
                print(r.decode())
            else:
                chan.send('exit')
                print('exiting')
                bhSession.close()
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        bhSession.close()
```

But when I try:

```
ssh tim@127.0.0.1
```

and type the password, I get in the client side:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

and in the server side:

```
[+] Listening for connection ...
[+] Got a connection! from ('127.0.0.1', 53674)
[+] Authenticated!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/ssh_man_in_the_middle/./sshserver.py", line 52, in <module>
    chan.send('Welcome to bh_ssh')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 801, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed
```

`lsof /dev/pts` doesn't seem to indicate I'm reaching the limit of 256 used terminals. I also can't `umount /dev/pts` because I always get *"target is busy".*

What can I do to proceed?

I managed to ssh in my own computer and `umount` and `mount` again my `/dev/pts`. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you actually do not implement the PTY in your server.

You have to implement the [`ServerInterface.check_channel_pty_request`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/server.html#paramiko.server.ServerInterface.check_channel_pty_request). The default implementation just return `True`. And that's why the SSH client fails.

Though I'm not sure that you actually need to do that. Does your software even use PTY when it *"communicates via ssh"*?